# How to specify some attribute that child must have in python?

Tags: python

I have a parent class Gun, like below:

```
class Gun(object):
    def shoot(self):
        # for example: 'shoot with silver_bullet'
        print('shoot with %s' self.bullet)
```

As you can see this class do not have the bullet attribute so there will be exception if run the method.

Actually I hope other people will write child class of this class and do not forget to provide the bullet attribute.

Is there any good way to make sure the child class always implement this?

Like the abstract method way.. if child class do not implement some abstract method and run there will be exception

Comment: Are you using Py2 or Py3.6?

Comment: See the duplicate. If you are using Python 3.6 there is actually a much easier way by implementing `__init_subclass__`

Comment: It`s not the same. The other question is talking about let sub class implement a method.  What I want is to make sure the sub class have certain attribute. Not method